# Can you recommend neural network suitable for finding minimum and maximum of numbers in list with some noisy data?

Tags: neural-networks, noise, range

Let's have a list of integer numbers. These are generated about some "center" value with some tolerance +/-. I call this the "range". Also - there is some noise - the numbers are not in range.

[image: numbers plotted]

Each circle represents signal received from an antenna in one cycle. The max is length of the cycle, so the value of the number is the offset in the cycle. The point is that each signal should be caught in some expected time offset - call it the "center", but the real physical properties of the antenna makes the antenna catch the signals earlier or later, so this creates acceptable tolerance. However there can be ghost, invalid or whatever wrong signals out of tolerance, which should be discarded.

I need to find the the range - the center and the tolerance - the green line and the red boundaries. Can a neural network solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Neural networks can do lots of things and you can probably get one to somehow do this, but this does not really sound like a problem where a neural network would be the obvious choice.

It would seem more obvious to describe this kind of data using a mixture distribution. I.e. you have some kind of distribution such as a lognormal, normal or uniform (or whatever else) distribution that describes what happens within the red bars (and values outside those bars are either very rare under this distribution or even impossible - you'd have to decide how to handle that bit based on the context/subject matter knowledge of the problem), while the remainder of the distribution is described by another distribution (e.g. a lognormal or log-student-t with much higher variance).

Comment: I've edited the question describing real problem, does it change something in your statement? I really thought that this "be intelligent, find something and filter noise" kind of problem is great for NN...

Comment: A neural net is way overkill for this kind of application. This kind of outlier detection process would be well-handled by a parametric solution like a mixture model, especially in one dimension.

Comment: Although probably for non-negative integer values, a Poisson mixture seems much more suitable than normal/lognormal/uniform

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to make a neural network do this kind of thing, but as I said it would not be the first thing I think off. It can be hard to encode subject matter knowledge into them, if you already understand a lot about the physical process so I'd suspect you'd be better off with a more traditional approach. Additionally, you'd have to somehow find a training objective to train it with (e.g. in a supervised fashion by giving it lots and lots of real examples with the desired results given).

Comment: @alanocallaghan: Why Poisson? If it's continuous positive numbers log-normal (or log of some Student-T, if one wants longer tails) or gamma (or uniform, if it is really uniform within a band) seem to fit, right?

Comment: @Björn: "number of events in a fixed time" is the raison d'etre of a Poisson distribution.

Comment: @alanocallaghan Oh, you understood the data to be that? I got the impression that it was a continuous number (like strength of signal or frequency). The original poster will know that, I suppose, and then pick an appropriate distribution. And, yes, if it were a number of events (0,1,2,3,4....) in a time interval, then Poisson (or negative binomial) would indeed be an option.

Comment: @Björn yes, the OP states it's a Poisson process basically. "a list of integer numbers", "Each circle represents signal received from an antenna in one cycle[...] The point is that each signal should be caught in some expected time offset". Having said that it looks like a reasonable set of observations for a Poisson or NB without outliers.

Comment: The number represents an time offset in the time cycle, imagine it as "angle" in full circle. Anyway I am lost at what to do next knowing (or not) a right distribution. It is that my knowledge of probability is like zero, but that is of course out of scope of this question :)

Comment: @TomHANAX if you post some example data it might be possible to provide a concrete solution.

Comment: If these are angles, why are they integers? Is that just because results get rounded? If they are really continuous underneath, then one possible distribution that can capture values between 0 and some maximum (especially if the numbers "don't wrap around" = if 0 is not the same thing as the maximum, as in some sense could be the case with angles?!) is a beta-distribution (if you re-scale all your numbers to lie between 0 and 1). cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution

Comment: As stated in description, these numbers are offsets in time cycle. Since this come from program (Java), the numbers are in miliseconds. You can represent it or imagine it as angle or whatever you want, but in physical reality the property is continuous value representing some fraction in time. The time in its essence is not cyclical, but of course the offset in the cycle is, so I would say the numbers are maybe cyclical, because 0 represents same offset as maximum, but one cycle less. Hope it makes sense.